# Remove sidebar from laravel nova tool

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

So as the title suggests im looking at trying to remove the sidebar from a laravel nova tool i have created that we are looking at putting up on a tv to show sales stats. I would prefer not to have to put the board up with the navigation

Comment: Did you tried something? Like use css to hide it?

Comment: Do you mean remove the navigation link or the entire sidebar? If the former, simply remove any markup from the navigation.blade.php file in your tool's resources/views directory.

Comment: You get anywhere with this? I want to do the same thing... the ability to collapse (hide) it completely would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this:

copy the file in vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php and put it in /resources/views/vendor/nova.

You will then have control of the main Laravel nova layout and can add code to hide the sidebar when you are in the custom tool. You can copy over the rest of the views while you are at it.